# RecyclerView custom change animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have a game which uses a `RecyclerView` to create a horizontal "Stages" view. When the player passes the current stage I want to add a simple hop animation to the view containing the "Stage" the user just passed. I've tried using normal `Animations`, but haven't been able to get them to work correct.

The [documentation of the `animateChange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#animateChange(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method of `ItemAnimator` sounds like it's a good place to do this, but I haven't had any luck finding good documentation on how to implement a custom animation here.

I'm looking for advice, pointer to documentation on how to create custom animations on item change, or a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by using a [CycleInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/CycleInterpolator.html)